# regarding a set of integro-PDE

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, functional-equations

Let say I have a minimal example that contains most of the mathematics I am looking for. The example is as follows:

\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial u^0}{\partial t}(x,t)+\frac{\partial^2 u^0}{\partial x^2}(x,t)
+ u^0(x,t)\frac{\partial u^0}{\partial x}(x,t)\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\;\;+\int_0^1\!\!\!\int_0^t u^1(x,t;x_1,t_1)\frac{\partial u^1}{\partial x}(x,t;x_1,t_1)dt_1 dx=0\\
&\frac{\partial u^1}{\partial t}(x,t;x_1,t_1)+\frac{\partial^2 u^1}{\partial x^2}(x,t;x_1,t_1)+u^0(x,t)\frac{\partial u^1}{\partial x}(x,t;x_1,t_1)=0
\end{align}

wherein, $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $t\geq 0$. The initial and boundary conditions are as follows:

\begin{align}
&x=0: && u^0(0,t)=0\,, && u^1(0,t;x_1,t_1)=0\\
&x=1: && u^0(1,t)=1\,, && u^1(1,t;x_1,t_1)=0\\
&t=0: && u^0(x,0)=0\,, && u^1(x,0;x_1,t_1)=0
\end{align}

These are a coupled set of PDE in $(x,t)$, somewhat of first kind Fredholm integral equation WRT $x_1$ and somewhat of first kind Volterra integral equation WRT $t_1$.

Now here are my questions:

a) The variables $x_1$ and $t_1$ never appear outside the integrals, they are like mere parameters in the second equations, can we find a systematic way to find the dependency on $x_1$ and $t_1$ in $u^1$ or such a dependency is arbitrary?

*comment:* it seems $u^1$ can be considered as constant WRT these variables and also other dependencies are possible, but in some physical applications (*not applicable to mine for lack of symmetry here*) the researchers have Fourier transformed the equations and in the Fourier space both $k$ and $k^1$ have appeared in the equations even outside the integrals, so not strange to see the answer is non-trivially depending on both $k$ and $k_1$.

b) Is there any efficient and easy method to solve such a system of equations?

Answer (score 0):

The method of Fourier transform in each variable is a powerful one. $u(x,t)\to \hat{u}(\xi, t)\to \tilde{\hat{u}}(\xi, \omega)$ turns integro-differential equations into a set of algebraic equations that can be easily solved.